# Eclipse Counterclockwise: How do I add clojure/contrib/sql to my class path.

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib, counterclockwise

In my code, I have: 
    (ns Test.core
       (:require clojure.contrib.sql)
    )

The error statement is the following:
FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/contrib/sql__init.class or clojure/contrib/sql.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)

How do I fix this? Please give very detailed step by step instructions to doing this. I know there are other questions on this before but I'm unable to comment to ask and I can't exactly follow the instructions bc I'm new to eclipse manipulating files in general.

Please help.

Comment: For one, clojure.contrib.sql is old and deprecated. Now it's called java.jdbc. You need to add [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.3"] to your dependencies in project.clj.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a `:require` to work successfully the relevant `.jar` file needs to be available on the Java classpath.

You can set this up manually, but typically it is better to add the dependency using either Leiningen (`project.clj`) or Maven (`pom.xml`) - either of which will automatically download and set up the dependencies for you.

Comment: So what statement do I add to the project.clj file in order to do that? (Or what are the steps to doing that?)

Comment: Should CounterClockWise load up anything that I add to the Java build Path in my Eclipse project?